# Configuration about websphere (WAS) 7 with Windows 7

Tags: java, websphere

HI All,
         I am working on WAS 7 and i am using windows 7 operating system and IE9 so can anyone suggest me what kind of good PC configuration i needed because my PC is getting hanged when i started worked on this... so PC Configuration will be like RAM ? processor ? like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this for the bare minimum requirements.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27012421

Ensure that the memory is far higher than what is stated in this document. 1 GB is certainly not adequate.

It also depends on what you are running on this box (besides WebSphere App Server)

How many instances (or servers) of WAS are you running on it. Have about 1.5 GB (not referring to the JVM Heap here but the whole java process) per server instance as a ball park to have a reasonable performance.

HTH

Manglu